# Login page - disable/removing text "get facebook for android and browse faster"

Tags: android, facebook, api

Is any way how remove disable follow text :
"get facebook for android and browse faster"
from login page. problem what i have with that is that I build application what I convert for RIM BB PlayBook but because in their rules is not allowed have in app any things what showing to conect with android app cant be aprrove for appworld. Also weir is when I build application for facebook and on first page facebook say that their app is better and fast ....its really weird and it not seems as a support for developers.

Comment: post a screenshot. will help us know what you are talking about.